# Run C project automatically after boot

Tags: boot

I have followed the http://www.adapteva.com/white-papers/building-linux-for-parallella-platform and Booting went well. How would I get my C code to run automatically after the parallella boots up?

Answer (score 0):

you can put the script into ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc

Comment: it is a headless image, can you please explain more how can I run my C program in the ARM processor, I have created a C project in SDK that should be run on the zynq PS and should write and read from the PL

Comment: I'm only connected to the board by Putty terminal

Comment: and I want my C project to run automatically after it boots up

Comment: you have to compile and make your code executable and then edit the mentioned files.